# Excel If/Then Statement

Tags: excel

I'm looking to do the following:

If B2 is greater than A2, multiply B2 by 2%
If B2 is less than or equal to A1, multiply B2 by 1%

```
=OR((B2>A2,(B2)*0.02,0),(B2<=A2,(B2)*0.01,0))
```

Comment: OR statements return TRUE if either one of the conditions is valid. They are useful when used as an IF condition, for example.

Answer (score 2):

in excel, if statement covers both the if and else.

```
=IF(logic statement, value if true, value if false)
```

so all you need to do is

```
=IF(B2>A2, B2*0.02, B2*0.01)
```

In this case, if `B2 > A2`, `B2*0.02` will run. If that is not true, when `B2 <= A2`, then `B2*0.01` will run.